# Extract ID / Class information from HTML page with VBA

Tags: html, vba, excel

I wrote a while ago a program in Excel VBA that can read a HTML page and extract specific information about the price of my game collection. It was working fine until a month ago where everything stops working and I can't get why it doesn't work anymore and I need some help to solve that.

so here the code

```
    Dim htm As Object           ' tableau HTML venant du site pricecharting
    ' Find price over internet
    With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
       .Open "GET", "http://videogames.pricecharting.com/game/" & console & "/" & name & "", False
       .Send
       htm.body.innerhtml = .responsetext
    End With

    ' what I want is in a table row 1 and cell 0 (used price)
    Cells(ligne + 1, 3).Value = htm.getelementbyid("price_data").Rows(1).Cells(0).innerText
```

and here is an example page where "console" has been replaced by nintendo-64 and "name" by mario-kart-64:

https://www.pricecharting.com/game/nintendo-64/mario-kart-64

```
<div id="price_data" class="info_box">
        <div id="used_price">
            <h3>Loose <span>Price</span></h3>
            <p class="price">
        $44.60
            </p>
            <p class="js-show-tab volume" data-show-tab="completed-auctions-used">
    <span class="tablet-portrait-hidden">Volume:&nbsp;</span>
    <a href="#">3 sales per day</a>
</p>
        </div>

        <div id="complete_price">
            <h3>Complete <span>Price</span></h3>
            <p class="price">
        $65.99
            </p>
            <p class="js-show-tab volume" data-show-tab="completed-auctions-cib">
    <span class="tablet-portrait-hidden">Volume:&nbsp;</span>
    <a href="#">2 sales per week</a>
</p>
        </div>

        <div id="new_price">
            <h3>New <span>Price</span></h3>
            <p class="price">


        $178.14


            </p>
            <p class="js-show-tab volume" data-show-tab="completed-auctions-new">
    <span class="tablet-portrait-hidden">Volume:&nbsp;</span>
    <a href="#">2 sales per month</a>
</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

my goal (that I succeed) was to go and extract the price $44.60 but then, like I said, it doesn't work anymore, I got the error '-2147024891 (80070005)': access denied.

Can someone help me? I'm quite new at this so most of the information I find are too complicated for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your code does not initialize the `htm` object as you attempt to write the innerhtml text to it. Possibly, your post is not showing all the code. Consider using a `HTMLFile` to hold the `responsetext` and then run your search on the html object:

```
Public Sub WebScrape()
    Dim htm As Object, doc As Object

    Set htm = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set doc = CreateObject("HTMLFile")

    With htm
       .Open "GET", "http://videogames.pricecharting.com/game/" _
                       & console & "/" & Name & "", False
       .Send
       doc.Open
       doc.write .responsetext
       doc.Close
    End With

    Cells(ligne + 1, 3).Value = doc.getelementbyid("price_data").Rows(1).Cells(0).innerText

    Set doc = Nothing
    Set htm = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: it is all the code that I use to extract the information i need. I tried your solution but it didn't work, the program still stop at the ".send " command and pop me the error message. could it be that on a possible update, the "package"  MSXML2.XMLHTTP requiered to perform the task I want has been block ??

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved my problem !

```
 ' Search price over internet
    With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
        .Open "GET", "http://videogames.pricecharting.com/game/" & console & "/" & name & "", False
        .Send
        htm.body.innerhtml = .responsetext
    End With

    ' Search the price with the state of the game (completed ou cartridge only)
    If consoleandname(3) <> "Completed set" Then

        ' the information we search is found with ID used_price
        Cells(ligne + 1, 3).Value = htm.getelementbyid("used_price").innertext

    ElseIf consoleandname(3) = "Completed set" Then

       ' the information we search is found with ID completed_price
        Cells(ligne + 1, 3).Value = htm.getelementbyid("complete_price").innertext
    End If
```

so instead of using msxml2.xmlhttp, I now use WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1 (but I'm not quite sure what is the difference). I find out that the HTML code has been modified because i succeed a first time to make it work again with the instruction :
    Cells(ligne + 1, 3).Value = htm.getelementbyid("price_data").getElementsByTagName("p")(0).innertext

but then the next day, that solution wasn't working anymore so i tried the current one show previously and it work fine. by looking at the HTML code I noticed that it was different so mayby that's the reason WHY my original code stop working and that i need to change for WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1